# ResellersPanel API is giving me domain errors even after I put the "domain" type

Tags: php, api

I am using Resellers Panel API. I am trying to create a simple order form in PHP. I am following this documentation : https://cp.resellerspanel.com/downloads/ResellersPanelAPI.pdf

I manage to go this far.

```
$data = Array(
"section"=>"order",
"command"=>"create",
"firstname"=>$first_name,
"lastname"=>$last_name,
"email"=>$email,
"address1"=>$address1,
"city"=>$city,
"zip"=>$zip,
"ip"=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
"country"=>$country,
"phone"=>$phone,

"plan"=>65209,
"period"=>12, 
"payment_method"=>"Wallet",
"return_url"=>"https://www.lcsitmediahosting.com/",
"price_type"=>"wholesale",
"domains"=>Array("type"=>"register")
);
```

It accepted all the inputs fine. until I got to the domains. it gives me these error.

`No type provided for domain h.h, must be register, transfer or existing`
or `Invalid Domain parameters` if I do not include it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. multiple commands option should be used instead. issues with the API